# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined. Discord.JS V 12.3.1

Tags: javascript

I've looked into this a lot and none of my dependencies coincide with what people are saying to upgrade/downgrade. I believe it has to do with react which I do not have installed. I tried installing them to see if that would help but to no avail.

I'm using:
Discord.js V 12.3.1
Fs V 0.0.1-security
nodemon 2.04
path 0.012.7
and of course, all of their dependencies.

Here is the bit having an issue:

```
    commandHandler(path){
this.fs.readdirSync(this.path.normalize(path)).map((f) => {
    const File = require (this.path.join(__dirname, `..`, path, f));
    this.commands.set(File.name, File);
})
```

Comment: there is a problem with the value of `path` variable he expect it to have a value but there is nothing on it

Comment: what is this.path?

Comment: this.path = require('path');